# Difficulty providing a saliva sample for DNA testing

Tags: dna

I find it difficult for medical reasons to generate the spit needed to do a genealogy DNA test. What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

There are DNA testing companies that use cheek swabs rather than saliva for DNA tests: FamilyTreeDNA and MyHeritage are the two largest of these.

If, on the other hand, you already have a kit (e.g.) from Ancestry that requires saliva, [Ancestry](https://support.ancestry.co.uk/s/article/UK-Taking-a-DNA-Test) say:

> Difficulty producing enough saliva?
>
> If you can’t produce enough saliva in one try, refrigerate your tube in an upright position between attempts. You can refrigerate your sample for up to a week before needing to add it to the blue solution in the saliva tube.

There is also a suggested [solution here](http://anotherteenmom.com/reviews/how-to-do-an-ancestrydna-test-without-spit/) but I've no experience of it so can't say whether it will work or not.